# Can View call some Model methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, rails-activerecord

First let me explain an example:

In **Model**:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items

  def income
     self.line_items.sum(:price)
  end

  def cost
    self.line_items.sum(:cost)
  end

  def profit
    self.income - self.cost
  end
end
```

Then in **Controller**:

```
def show
  @products = Product.all
end
```

And in View:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
Product Name: <%= product.name %>
Product Income: <%= product.income %>
Product Cost: <%= product.cost %>
Product Profit: <%= product.profit %>
<% end %>
```

Is it a good practice to call **model** methods from **view**?

When I searched for that, I found many people saying it is NOT a good practice to ever call model methods or access DB from views.

And on the other hand, some others said that don't call class methods or any method updates the DB from view but you can access any method that only retrieve data.

Then, is this code a good practice?

Answer (score 9):

Its perfectly fine to call the object-methods/attributes from the view, as long as the call would not change the data. I mean, call readers/getters. A Bad practice would be to call/invoke methods that update/delete the data. Don't call setters.

Also, if there is any complex computation involved, resort to helpers.

Answer (score 3):

Since your methods need to access `line_items` association, to avoid N+1 problem and calling DB queries from view, I'd advice fetching your `line_items` in `show` action, with `includes`:

```
def show
  @products = Product.includes(:line_items)
end
```

With this adjustment, I think it's ok to call these methods in view.

Comment: But actually, I don't need to load line items object. However, I just need to do a sum in the query.